# robot_pose_ekf is not active

Tags: navigation, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello ı need to use robot_pose_ekf to publish odom for gmapping. ı see my imu data but still robot_pose_ekf not active. I use static transform publisher imu to base_footprint.
what ı should  to do for that ?

this is my result of $ rosservice call /robot_pose_ekf/get_status:

[http://i.imgur.com/Fp4mQNM.png](https://i.imgur.com/Fp4mQNM.png)

```
status: Input:
 * Odometry sensor
   - is NOT active
   - received 0 messages
   - listens to topic /odom
 * IMU sensor
   - is active
   - received 5907 messages
   - listens to topic /imu_data
 * Visual Odometry sensor
   - is NOT active
   - received 0 messages
   - listens to topic 
Output:
 * Robot pose ekf filter
   - is NOT active
   - sent 0 messages
   - pulishes on topics /robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined and /tf
```

mine robot_pose_ekf launch file :

```
   <launch>
<node pkg="robot_pose_ekf" type="robot_pose_ekf" name="robot_pose_ekf">
  <param name="output_frame" value="odom"/>
  <param name="base_footprint_frame" value="base_footprint"/>
  <param name="freq" value="30.0"/>
  <param name="sensor_timeout" value="1.0"/>  
  <param name="odom_used" value="false"/>
  <param name="imu_used" value="true"/>
  <param name="vo_used" value="false"/>
</node>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212576/robot_pose_ekf-is-not-active/) by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2015-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ı solved this problem like this:

robot_pose_ekf package need a /odom message. only /imu_data message (UM7) not enough for this package.So you need to publish a/ odom message from another package. ı published /pose2D message with laser_Scan_matcher package and ı transformed it /odom message like that  /pose2D ---> /odom.

and in the end, robot_pose_ekf is active now with /odom and /imu_data messages.

---

Originally posted by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) with karma: 153 on 2015-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0